# Erro no mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de *login* e senha só que esta dando o problema e não sei como resolver se alguém poder me dar o código já editado agradeço

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($conexao, "admin");
    session_start();
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            function sucesso(){
                setTimeout("window.location='index.php'", 4000);
            }
            function failed(){
                setTimeout("window.location='login.html'", 4000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $user = $_POST["user"];
            $pass = $_POST["pass"];

            $consulta = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user' AND senha = '$pass'") or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
            $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

            if($linhas == 0){
                echo"O login falhou. Você será redirecionado para a página de login em 4 segundos.";
                echo"<script language='javascript'>failed()</script>";
            } else {
                $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["user"];
                $_SESSION["senha"]=$_POST["pass"];
                echo"Você foi logado com sucesso. Redirecionando em 4 segundos.";
                echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\programas\htdocs\autenticar.php on line 25

Comment: "se alguém poder me dar o código já editado" não é assim que o SOpt funciona. Você leu a mensagem de erro? Ela está muito clara: te dá a linha do erro, a função onde está o erro e diz o que está errado.

Comment: o problema e que nao consigo solucionar sou iniciante em php e estou aprendendo ainda se poder me ajudar agradeço

Comment: O que entendeu da mensagem de erro?

Comment: entendi que o "mysqli_query ()" esta esperando pelo menos 2 parâmetros mas só está constando 1, mas não sei qual é este parâmetro que ele está pedindo @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: E já leu a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) da função para descobrir qual é este parâmetro?

Comment: tentei ler mais nao consigo amigo

Comment: Tem a lista de parâmetros lá. Não tem muita dificuldade. O primeiro parâmetro que a função espera é `$link`, que é o retorno de `mysqli_connect` e o segundo é `$query`, referente ao comando SQL. Crie o costume de ler a documentação em seus estudos e, principalmente, aprenda a utilizá-la. Nela tem (praticamente) tudo sobre a linguagem.

Comment: se nao fosse pedir de mais nao poderia me dar uma solução rápida e definitiva?

Comment: É pedir demais, sim. A solução é clara e rápida. Basta você estudar um pouco as funções que está utilizando. Não adianta aplicar códigos que você não sabe o que faz.

Comment: certo valei ai desculpa pelo incomodo